# Select all indexes of a type in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle10g

How does one go about selecting all indexes of a specific type in Oracle 10g, for instance I want all of the `bitmap` indexes that are declared.

I imagine the query would be something like this:

```
select * from system_indexes where type = 'bitmap'
```

but that is definitely not correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_indexes
 WHERE index_type IN ('BITMAP', 'FUNCTION-BASED BITMAP' )
```

is probably what you're looking for (though you may want just the indexes where `index_type = 'BITMAP'`.  If you are only concerned with indexes on tables that you have `SELECT` access on, you can query `all_indexes` rather than `dba_indexes`.  If you are only concerned with indexes in the current schema, you can query `user_indexes` rather than `dba_indexes`.